# Java failing to initialise classes to represent geoJson structure

Tags: java

I am trying to initialise classes to represent geoJson structure as follows:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ACCESS": "N",
        "TAG": "T",
        "CROSSINGTIMEHRS": 0,
        "COUNTRYCODE": "USA",
        "GROUPID": 699
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [[-0.426321,51.3882268],[-0.4183388,51.3946538],
                        [-0.4183388,51.3946538],[-0.415678,51.3982953],
                        [-0.415678,51.3982953],[-0.4083824,51.4049886]]
      }
    }
 }
```

My classes are as follows:

### Features.java

```
public class Features {

    public String type;
    public Geometry geometry;
    public Properties properties;

    public Features() {
        this.type = "Feature";
        this.geometry = new Geometry();
        this.properties = new Properties();
    }
}
```

### Geometry.java

```
public class Geometry {

    public String type;
    public List<Coordinates> coordinates;

    public Geometry() {
        this.type = "LineString";
        this.coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

### Coordinates.java

```
public class Coordinates {

    public double lat;
    public double lon;

    public Coordinates() {
        this.lat = 0.0;
        this.lon = 0.0;
    }
}
```

### Properties.java

```
public class Properties {

    public String ACCESS;
    public String TAG;
    public String COUNTRYCODE;
    public double CROSSINGTIMEHRS;
    public int GROUPID;

    public Properties() {
        this.ACCESS = "";
        this.TAG = "";
        this.COUNTRYCODE = "UK";
        this.CROSSINGTIMEHRS = 0.0;
        this.GROUPID = 0;
    }
}
```

When initialising `Features` everything is set correctly to default values except the latlongs found in `Coordinates/java`

`Features bridge = new Features();` gives:[image]

As can be seen coordinates has a size of 0. During debugging I realised that I am not entering the `Coordinates` constructor, but I fail to understand why.

How can I add the default values for `lat` and `long` to the coordinate arraylist upon initialisation?

Comment: In your JSON, `coordinates` is represented as a matrix of double values - I believe this should be an array of lat/lon pairs, no?  e.g. "coordinates" : [{"lat":1.2, "lon":3.4}, ...].

Comment: According to the `GeoJSON` standard https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.1, the coordinates of LineString are an array of positions as above. If you check page 5 of the document there is an example.

Answer (score 0):

In **Geometry.java** you write `this.coordinates = new ArrayList<>();` which means this.coordinates is `new ArrayList<>()` -> empty Array list.

```
this.coordinates = new Coordinates();
```

will load default lon/lat from **Coordinates.java**

```
public class Geometry {

    public String type;
    public List<Coordinates> coordinates;

    public Geometry() {
        this.type = "LineString";
        this.coordinates = Lists.newArrayList(new Coordinates());
    }
}
```

For  `Lists.newArrayList` just import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How will object of type `Coordinates` be converted to `List<Coordinates>`? This will give an incompatible types error.

Comment: Updated. Take a look Hope to help 'u!.